# Terraform provisioner for multiple instances

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to accomplish adding 2 instances to a file called aws_worker_nodes_IP. This is the code below...again...I do not just need one worker IP listed I need both or all if my variables were to change.

I was told to use self.public_IP but that just list one. I need it for both.

```
#-----key pair for Workernodes-----

resource "aws_key_pair" "k8s-node_auth" {
  key_name   = "${var.key_name2}"
  public_key = "${file(var.public_key_path2)}"
}

#-----Workernodes-----

resource "aws_instance" "nodes-opt-us1-k8s" {
  instance_type = "${var.k8s-node_instance_type}"
  ami           = "${var.k8s-node_ami}"
  count         = "${var.NodeCount}"

  tags {
    Name = "nodes-opt-us1-k8s"
  }

  key_name               = "${aws_key_pair.k8s-node_auth.id}"
  vpc_security_group_ids = ["${aws_security_group.opt-us1-k8s_sg.id}"]
  subnet_id              = "${aws_subnet.opt-us1-k8s.id}"

#-----Link Terraform worker nodes to Ansible playbooks-----

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOD
cat <<EOF > aws_worker_nodes_IP
[workers]
${self.public_ip}     <------need both here not just one
EOF
EOD
  }
}

#----this has two nodes-----     "count = "${var.NodeCount}"
```

Sorry if I did not explain correctly in my first question, and I appreciate the help. I have only been working with terraform for a few months. Also, I am a Network Engineer learning to write code.

Comment: Does `${self.*.public_ip}` work? I know with count you can use their splat syntax.

Comment: If local-exec gets executed once for each count then when you cat into the file you are using `>` which will overwrite instead of appending it.

Comment: Ah...such a noob question, but what symbol would append instead of overwrite then?

Comment: >> will append to existing file (creating new at first execution)

Comment: `>>` will append to the file if it exists or create one if it does not already exist so each run it will append after the first.

Comment: Thanks man. I appreciate the help...that worked

Comment: Nice, just be aware it may continue to append after each time you run if the file already exists creating duplicate entries.